# Limit of piecewise function and find a

Tags: limits, piecewise-continuity

[image]

I calculated the limit for 1 ^ - and found it infinite. But for 1 ^ + I can't find a when the 2nd function equals infinity. What solution should I do?

Comment: What about playing around with the graphs using a slider?
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ffewdtmkmo

Comment: that's incredible!. thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right limit at $x=1$ is $$RL=\lim_{h\to 0} [2(1+h)-4+3^\frac{1+h}{1-(1+h)^2}$$
$$RL=-2+\lim_{h \to 0}3^{\frac{(1+h)}{1-(1+2h)}}=-2+\lim_{h\to 0}3^{\frac{1+h}{-2h}}=-2$$
Left limit at $x=1$ is
$$LL=\frac{8}{\pi}\tan^{-1}a $$
Finally, $LL=RL$ gives $a=-1$.

Comment: thank you so much!